# Output of the design is not as I did - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

This is my UI page that I want it to appear on my physical emulator
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXD5r.png) and this is the expected output
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AsNs.png)

**Android UI Design Problem**
I really don't know why that is happening I used actually Relativelayout and thanks in advance
I don't use XML a lot so I'm kinda new to using UI stuff here in android
and here is my XML code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.example.splash.StartActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/zeroPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pexels_george_sultan_1409999" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="186sp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fixNowImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fixnowtheoriginallogo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="31sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fixNowImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="165sp"

            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold_italic"
            android:text="Fix"
            android:textColor="#f05454"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nowPart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="31sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fixNowImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fix"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold_italic"
            android:text="Now"
            android:textColor="#30475e"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subLogoPart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fix"

            android:layout_marginLeft="123sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:text="Sharing smile through car caring"
            android:textColor="#30475e"
            android:textSize="10sp"

            android:textStyle="normal" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstPart"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80sp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_CreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="364sp"
            android:layout_height="55sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24sp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_31"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="9sp"
            android:text="Create an account"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            tools:text="Create an account" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_SignIn"
            android:layout_width="364sp"
            android:layout_height="55sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button_CreateAccount"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24sp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_32"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="9sp"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="#30475e"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            tools:text="Sign in" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondPart"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44sp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/firstLineOfOr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9.5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11.5sp"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_line_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/theOR"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstLineOfOr"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
            android:text="Or"
            android:textColor="#49454f"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/SecondLineOfOr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9.5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="23.5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11.5sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/theOR"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_line_1" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fourthPart"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thirdPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_LoginWithGoogle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24sp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_1451"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_google"
            android:drawablePadding="12.5sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="7sp"
            android:paddingLeft="103.6sp"
            android:text="Login with Google"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="#30475e"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_LoginWithFacebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button_LoginWithGoogle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24sp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_1451"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_facebook"
            android:drawablePadding="12.2sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="7sp"
            android:paddingLeft="109.2sp"
            android:text="Login with Google"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="#30475e"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        />


    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're doing a lot of your horizontal positioning with absolute values, like `android:layout_marginLeft="165sp"` for your *Fix* text, or `android:paddingLeft="103.6sp"` for your login buttons. If your physical device doesn't match the design view (different screen size/resolution) then those numbers won't be right, and it'll broken on any devices that don't match. Also you're using `sp` instead of `dp`, which means those numbers depend on the user's font size settings and the final distances could vary wildly

Comment: Honestly you should probably just learn to use ConstraintLayout - it'll be way easier to work with (and your "expected output" image is using it, you can see the constraints marked on it) and you can easily centre stuff and be sure it'll be centred on all screens, like with a *packed chain* (https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain) for your *Fix* and *Now* texts

Comment: Thank you so much I'mma just tryna see how to use constraint layout cause I'm still facing issues in other xml pages

Answer (score 0):

Try this xml code , where I edited your xml with some small corrections. I haven't corrected padding to image on button, but that can be done easily upon your requirements.

Instead of using `Button` you could also try using `TextView` inside any `Layout` and add an `ImageView` at the required position. Hope this solves your issue.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#fff"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/zeroPart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5sp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
   </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstPart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="186sp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fixNowImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fixnowtheoriginallogo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fix"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fixNowImage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Fix"
            android:textColor="#f05454"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nowPart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Now"
            android:textColor="#30475e"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subLogoPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fix"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
        android:text="Sharing smile through car caring"
        android:textColor="#30475e"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

   </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondPart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstPart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_CreateAccount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_31"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="9sp"
        android:paddingStart="80dp"
        android:paddingEnd="80dp"
        android:text="Create an account"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        tools:text="Create an account" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_SignIn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_31"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="9sp"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#30475e"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        tools:text="Sign in" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/thirdPart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/secondPart"
    android:layout_marginTop="40sp">

    <!--        <ImageView-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/firstLineOfOr"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginLeft="24sp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginTop="9.5sp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginBottom="11.5sp"-->
    <!--            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_down" />-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theOR"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
        android:text="Or"
        android:textColor="#49454f"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <!--        <ImageView-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/SecondLineOfOr"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginLeft="17sp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginTop="9.5sp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginRight="23.5sp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginBottom="11.5sp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/theOR"-->
    <!--            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_down" />-->


   </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fourthPart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thirdPart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_LoginWithGoogle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_1451"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_google"
        android:drawablePadding="12.5sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="7sp"
        android:paddingStart="103.6sp"
        android:text="Login with Google"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#30475e"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_LoginWithFacebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_1451"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_facebook"
        android:drawablePadding="12.2sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="7sp"
        android:paddingStart="109.2sp"
        android:text="Login with Fb"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#30475e"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```